# Laptop shows battery is 4% charged, but it is charged to maximum

Tags: batteries, laptop

I got old acer computer and i noticed that when I plug in charger, it says it is charging, but after 5 hours it still was 4% only, so i decided to get out battery and check it with manualy using multimeeter.All cells were charged to maximum, but laptop shows it is only 4% charged.

Comment: How did you check that all cells are charged to maximum? Voltage alone is not enough, you e.g. need some load. I would switch the laptop on and see how long the cells last. Note that the cells wear out over time and have something like memory effect. My laptop charges to 100%, but also says that the capacity is only 80% of design capacity. One other hint: Some laptops have the option to re-calibrate the 'scale', but I do not know more about it.

Comment: I checked every battery separetly, and every of them is charged to 4.08, i think it is very good

Comment: At the place I work, with 1000's of employees all equipped with laptop computers, to see many of the batteries get to a fraction of their original hold up time after a couple of years of usage. It would not be unexpected that an old laptop computer that you acquire could have a very tired battery. A new battery purchase should always be a consideration in the acquisition cost of a used laptop computer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing battery voltage with actual battery capacity.

The charging system may be doing coulomb counting to determine state of charge. As such, it would actually measure the amount of *power* going into the battery. Considering you say the laptop is old, it's possible the battery can only store 4% of the power it could when new.

Basically, measuring the voltage only tells you if it's currently fully charged, not how much energy "fully charged" represents. Coulomb counting can track actual capacity.

Comment: I left laptop turned on for 2 hours, everything worked great, but when i check, every time it says 4% remaining ...

Comment: @Ricky: Why not let your turned off laptop charge for a good long time - say overnight - then disconnect the charger and run the laptop until it shuts itself down, then repeat the cycle a few times and see what happens?

Comment: I fount the problem, it seems that sensors went bad, i use laptop for good amount of time - say 4-5 hours - without charger, only thing is that i don't know exactly how much battery left.Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I bet you it is a battery balancer/management IC within the battery that is bad.